# How to map GeoPoint from Firebase - Firestore in to Kotlin DTO Object in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have Firestore implemented in my project, collection and documents, and in documents have field location which is GeoPoint with latitude and longitude. How can I map that to a Kotlin DTO Object which by the way needs to be parcelable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoPoint](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint) class does **not** implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) nor [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interfaces. So there is no way you can make that kind of object `Parcelable` or `Serializable`. If you need such functionality, you should **not** store the latitude and longitude using a `GeoPoint` but as simple properties of type `double`.

Comment: The easy way is to add new fields `double` latitude and longitude, yes, but i was wondering about the GeoPoint `Parcel`. That clarifies the things, thanks.